# How to display zero or date value if no records are displayed

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a union all query. but in my result set I have 2 P1 records and 3 P2 records.  I would like to still display 3 P3 records even if there are no values.

Please see my code below

```
SELECT 'P1'     AS Priority,
       Count(*) Total,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, logdate))
       + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, logdate)), 2)
FROM   dbo.mg_rpt_calls
WHERE  priority = 'P1'
       AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, logdate))
           + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, logdate)), 2) BETWEEN
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, Getdate()))
               + RIGHT(
               '00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, Getdate())-2), 2)AND
               CONVERT(
               VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, Getdate()))
               +
               RIGHT
               ('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, Getdate())), 2)
GROUP  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, logdate))
          + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, logdate)), 2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'P2'     AS Priority,
       Count(*) Total,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, logdate))
       + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, logdate)), 2)
FROM   dbo.mg_rpt_calls
WHERE  priority = 'P2'
       AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, logdate))
           + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, logdate)), 2) BETWEEN
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, Getdate()))
               + RIGHT(
               '00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, Getdate())-2), 2)AND
               CONVERT(
               VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, Getdate()))
               +
               RIGHT
               ('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, Getdate())), 2)
GROUP  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, logdate))
          + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, logdate)), 2)
ORDER  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, logdate))
          + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, logdate)), 2)
```

my result set is below

```
Priority Total (No column name)
P2       9     201209
P2       15    201210
P1       1     201210
P1       1     201211
P2       5     201211
```

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Sorry, I might be missing something - but where do the P3 records come from? There's no union for those...also, why are you using a union?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the group by at a lower level, such as:

```
SELECT Priority, Count(*) Total,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, logdate)) + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, logdate)), 2)
FROM   dbo.mg_rpt_calls
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, logdate))
           + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, logdate)), 2) BETWEEN
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, Getdate()))
               + RIGHT(
               '00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, Getdate())-2), 2)AND
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, Getdate())) +
               RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, Getdate())), 2)
group by Priority, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(yyyy, logdate)) + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datepart(mm, logdate)), 2)
```

You could optionally include another `where` clause or `having` clause to the effect of `priority in ('P1', 'P2', 'P3')`.